# importing sql dump file for a wordpress site error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to restore a mysql dump file for a wordpress site.

I am using mysql  Ver 14.14 on ubuntu 16.04

I tried this command as I have used it before with different projects

```
$ mysql -u USER -p NEW_DATABASE < DUMP_FILE.sql
```

I am getting this error after prompted for password

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 944: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   ''a:406:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:\"slug\";s:15:\"general_options\";s:6:\"parent\";s:15:\"gen'
>   at line 1

Comment: How did you acquire the dump file? in what version of mysql?

Comment: Can you try this syntax:mysql -u username -p[yourpassword]  database_name < dump.sql

Comment: I acquired the dump file using -
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
- the dump file was created last year but I don't know the mysql version.

Comment: using syntax:mysql -u username -p[yourpassword] database_name < dump.sql - generated same error.